# Calling a C compiler within Matlab in Windows

Tags: matlab, sdk

Matlab provides the shell escape command with the character `!`.
When I'm working with Matlab in Linux with GCC installed, I can use the following commands to compile a .c function and execute it:

```
!gcc the_c_function.c -o the_executable_file_name
!./ the_executable_file_name
```

If I have [SDK](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk.html) in Windows, is there an analogous command I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclamation mark is equivalent to `system()` in all OS.

Essentially it runs whatever is after it in the OS command line. `!` is not `gcc` or anything specific, you can run `!ls`, or `!cd ..`, or any other thing that command line would understand.  Therefore if you know how to compile your code and run from command line, its the same in MATLAB.

The SDK in MATLAB is a different stuff that is not at all related to the commands in your question. It allows you to compile MATLAB code, and make a library out of it.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I was more in doubt regarding how to replace the gcc command, in my case, I have Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, but indeed SDK is not a compiler in itself. Would you know the command for calling the MVS compiler?